# How can i return to Main.storyboard which contains a TabBarController from another Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have two storyboards, one which contains everything the app really is, and another which contains an "onboarding"/tutorial to my app.

Once the tutorial is done, I want to navigate back to my original view controller.

**This is my code to navigate to the other storyboard:**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if defaults.bool(forKey: "firstOpened") {
    print("First VC launched")
}else{
    var vc: UIViewController
    let goTo = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationStoryboard") as! FirstOnboardingViewController
    self.present(goTo, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}
```

With this, it works, except the TabBarController is not showing, and not working the way I want it to.

**And this is my code to navigate back to the Main.Storyboard:**

```
@objc func handleSecondPush() {
    //registerForRemoteNotifications() 
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstOpened")
    let goTo = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pushToFeedVC") 
    self.present(goTo, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLink", sender: nil)   
}
```

**I have also tried this in the other Storyboard, but with this the button doesn't change the view:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
print(controller)
self.window?.rootViewController = controller
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
if let tabBarVc = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarVc.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

**Question in short terms:** So my question is, how can I navigate back to the main.storyboard which will contain the TabBarController with a selected index of 1, from a storyboard that doesn't contain navigation controller or a TabBarController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you present the onbaording you should return back to the tab with with

```
self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```

for complex presentations you can do this for easy re-back

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController  
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = vc
```

---

What is better is to

```
  let goTo = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationStoryboard") as! FirstOnboardingViewController 
  let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:goTo)
  nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
  self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> the flow inside the onbarding should be with pushViewController

then to dismiss in the last onbaording vc

```
  if let tab =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
     tab.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but with this line of code it only dismisses the last viewcontroller in the "onboarding", and displays the first VC in the second Storyboard

Comment: Great it now works perfect, exactly what i was looking for! :) Thanks again for the awesome help Sh_Khan!